# Is this an impractical way of adding title attributes to links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I came up with a simple JavaScript function that selects all of the anchor tags on the page, selects the text wrapped in the link, and makes that value the title attribute.  Before it does that, it checks if that anchor tag already has a title attribute.

```
$("a").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).prop("title")) {
        var linkContent = $(this).text();
        $(this).prop("title", linkContent);
    }
});
```

I want to know, whether or not, if this is a practical solution.

Comment: What's your definition of practical here? Seems like a subjective question. Your code appears to work, so are you asking about coder preference or performance? Both would appear to be off-topic.

Comment: I just want to know if this is good practice?

Comment: Best practice would be to declare the title attributes when the anchor is written out. Either in the static html, or with whatever server side scripting you have access to. You're adding unneeded extra load to the client. It's trivial (probably), but they're should have been a better place to do this further upstream.

Comment: Its fine mate. It works. And in the case of a client side app built from a server supplied config is probably a neat little snippet to use if you need the title represented this way.

Comment: ```attr()``` would be more appropriate to add an ```attr```ibute :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to set the attribute when you create the node (e.g. when the page is rendered, or when you insert an `a` element into the DOM. That way you avoid an unnecessary DOM operation. It won't really affect your app (unless you have thousands of links), but it's a good principle to follow.

If that isn't an option, what you have is fine if you can rely on the link text containing a sensible title.

You could express the same logic a little more succinctly:

```
$('a:not([title])').attr('title', function() {
  return $(this).text();
})
```

Comment: I like this and it's very close to what I suggested below.  I'm curious if searching the anchors without title using the css selector the way you did it would be faster than what I did below?

Comment: It also seems a bit confusing that you are setting the attribute from within the function rather than just returning the value you wanted?  i.e., why not just say `$('a:not([title])').attr('title', function() { return $(this).text()); })`

Comment: @billynoah you're quite right - I mixed up 2 parts of a jsbin when copying my code in. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the iteration and do it like this:

```
$("a").prop("title", function() {
    return $(this).prop("title") ? $(this).prop("title") : $(this).text();
});
```